# android soft keyboard: onReceiveResult fire with RESULT_SHOWN following immediately by RESULT_HIDDEN

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, android-event

I want to detect when the soft keyboard is show and hidden. For this i do like this :

```
public class ALEditText extends EditText {
  private ALSoftInputListener mSoftInputListener;

  private static class SoftInputReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    private static final int RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_SHOWN = 2;
    private static final int RESULT_HIDDEN = 3;
    private static final int RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN = 0;
    private ALSoftInputListener mListener;

    public SoftInputReceiver(ALSoftInputListener listener) {
      super(null);
      this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onReceiveResult(int result, Bundle data) {
      switch (result) {
        case RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN /*0*/:
        case RESULT_SHOWN /*2*/:
          if (this.mListener != null) {
            this.mListener.onSoftInputShown();
          }
        case RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN /*1*/:
        case RESULT_HIDDEN /*3*/:
          if (this.mListener != null) {
            this.mListener.onSoftInputHidden();
          }
        default:
      }
    }
  }

  public void showSoftInput() {
    SoftInputReceiver receiver = new SoftInputReceiver(this.mSoftInputListener);
    InputMethodManager imm = getInputMethodManager();
    imm.showSoftInput(this, 0, receiver);
  }

  public void HideSoftInput() {
    SoftInputReceiver receiver = new SoftInputReceiver(this.mSoftInputListener);
    InputMethodManager imm = getInputMethodManager();
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0, receiver);
  }

  public void SetSoftInputListener(ALSoftInputListener listener) {
    this.mSoftInputListener = listener;
  }

  protected InputMethodManager getInputMethodManager() {
    return (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService("input_method");
  }

}
```

but i have a strange behavior that i can't understand, when i do showSoftInput then the virtual keyboard is show and the event onSoftInputShown is also raised BUT it's immediately followed by onSoftInputHidden and the keyboard is still visible! later if i hide the keyboard the event onSoftInputHidden will be not call again ... does someone can explain me what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - it's because I forgot the break in the case.